# copy_from_user - difficulty in copying double pointer from user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Structures involved are like the following.
    struct node {
        int a;
        int b;
    }

```
struct ioctl_node {
    struct node **ptr;
    int         count; //Stores the no of pointers this ptr is pointing to.
};
```

In user space, I have populated a structure of ioctl_node with `count = 3`.
And `ptr[0]` and `ptr[2]` is pointing to two structs of type node, whereas `ptr[1]` is `NULL`. I want this to be passed to kernel.
I have issued ioctl call to pass this info from user space to kernel space.

I did the following in kernel space.

```
struct ioctl_node k_node;

copy_from_user(&k_node, arg, sizeof(struct ioctl_node)) //arg is the source

//k_node.count is showing the right value what I have set in the user space.

struct node *tmp = NULL;
```

I then did, `copy_from_user(&tmp, k_node.ptr, sizeof(struct node *)` and this call is also returning success. 
But, I am having difficulty, in copying the full contents of `**ptr` properly in kernel space.
Can anybody plese help, how can I be able to do that. How should I do the next copy_from_user to copy all the contents. I tried, but its giving copy error.

Comment: Can't you change your specification to copy a contiguous memory zone? What would you do if some internal pointers fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy_from_user` copies one block of consecutive bytes from user space to kernel space. You'll need to first copy the `struct ioctl_node`, then copy the pointers to individual nodes, then copy the `struct node`'s in a loop. Be sure to allocate the right amount of memory. Since you know the number of nodes in advance, you can allocate an array of them.

```
struct node_data {
    size_t node_count;
    struct nodes *nodes;
};
struct node_data *read_nodes(struct ioctl_node_user_pointer *arg)
{
    struct node_data *nd = NULL;
    struct ioctl_node kin = {0};
    struct node *node_user_pointers = NULL;
    int i;
    int err;
    /* Step 1: retrieve the root node */
    nd = kmalloc(sizeof(*nd), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!nd) {
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto error;
    }
    if (copy_from_user(ioctl_node_user_pointer, &kin, sizeof(kin))) {
        err = -EFAULT;
        goto error;
    }
    if (kin->count < 0 || kin->count > ((size_t)-1)/sizeof(*nodes)) {
        err = -EINVAL;
        goto error;
    }
    nd->node_count = kin.count;
    /* Step 2: retrieve the pointers to individual nodes */
    node_user_pointers = kmalloc(sizeof(*node_user_pointers) * nd->node_count, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (node_user_pointers) {
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto error;
    }
    if (copy_from_user(kin->nodes, node_user_pointers, sizeof(*node_user_pointers) * nd->node_count)) {
        err = -EFAULT;
        goto error;
    }
    /* Step 3: retrieve the nodes themselves */
    nd->nodes = kmalloc(sizeof(*nodes) * nd->node_count, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!nd->nodes) {
        err = -ENOMEM;
        goto error;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < head.count; i++) {
        if (copy_from_user(node_user_pointers[i], nd->nodes + i, sizeof(nd->nodes[0]))) {
            err = -EFAULT;
            goto error;
        }
    }
    kfree(node_user_pointers);
    return nd;
error:
    if (nd) {
        kfree(nd->nodes);
        kfree(nd);
    }
    kfree(node_user_pointers);
    return ERR_PTR(err);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like enough: the first `copy_from_user` is a "shallow copy", so `kin.ptr` is still a pointer to user-space memory.  Because of that, `kin.ptr[i]` can't be done -- you'll have to allocate an array of pointers and copy them over before you can start copying individual nodes.  Or follow [@BasileStarymlevitch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch)'s advice and change the API to avoid double indirections.

Comment: I think you mean `if (!node_user_pointers)` before `return -ENOMEM` ;-)  There's an `ERR_PTR` helper in `linux/err.h` to return errors as pointers.  Unconditionally `kfree(node_user_pointers)` is safe as `kfree(NULL)` is a no-op.  Also, although this is getting a bit extreme with error checking for a simple example, it's good to verify that `sizeof() * count` doesn't overflow and wrap, or else this becomes an easy way for userspace to scribble over unallocated kernel memory.